# Has anyone been able to get Confluence.pm to add attachments?

Tags: perl, api, xml-rpc, confluence

If so can you provide the code. I am able to do almost everything else from creating new pages, modifying page attributes etc.. But I cannot seem to add attachments. I have read the official [conflunce Perl XML-RPC site and discussions](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFEXT/Perl+XML-RPC+client) but all the code fragments they show there don't seem to work for me.  Here is my hacked up attempt at it:

```
# The following command sort of worked:
# ~/bin/wikitool.pl -action attach_file -url $MYURL
# IT attached something but the file was empty
sub attach_file {
    my $confluence = XMLRPC::Lite->proxy($opts{server}."rpc/xmlrpc");
    my $token = $confluence->call("confluence1.login", $opts{login}, $opts{password})->result();

    # Fetch page
    my $page = FetchPage($opts{title});
    if (not $page) {
      dbg("$opts{title} page is missing.","FATAL");
    }

    my $pageId = SOAP::Data->type( string => $$page{id} );

    my $filename = "$ENV{HOME}/tmp/tmp0.gif";
    my $metadata = {
        fileName => $filename,
        contentType => "image/gif",
        comment => "Some random GIF",
    };
    if (not open FILE, "< $filename") {
        dbg("Could not open file $filename: $!\n","FATAL");
    }
    binmode FILE;
    my $data;
    $data .= $_ while (<FILE>);
    my $call = $confluence->addAttachment($pageId, $metadata, $data);

    my $fault = $call->fault();
    if (defined $fault) {
        dbg("could not attach $filename" . $call->faultstring(), "FATAL");
    }
    else {
      print "attached $filename\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were 95% of the way there. The secret sauce for me:

```
$data .= $_ while (<FILE>);
my $escaped_data = new RPC::XML::base64($data);
my $call = $confluence->addAttachment($pageId, $metadata, $escaped_data);
```

I'm sure this is way too late to be helpful, but maybe someone else will bump into it some day.

Comment: Thanks! I have moved on to other projects but thanks for adding some insight to the collective...

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at Chery Chase's use of SOAP instead of RPC for attachments.

See http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DISC/Perl+XML-RPC+client  well down in the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

xml-rpc is deprecated now in confluence. a lot of function currently doesn't work in xml-rpc interface. more works under soap.